# Programmatically access MSE in R's H2O Deeplearning

Tags: r, h2o

I'm working with the current version of H2O in R and following a ["deeplearning" example](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-2/blob/master/R/examples/Kaggle/MeetupKaggleAfricaSoil.R) which must've been created with an earlier version.

A challenge I'm having in adapting the old example code, is that I can't programmatically access the cross-validation statistics like MSE with code like:

`cvmodel@model$valid_sqr_error`

Upon inspecting the structure of the H2O model object, I'm able to find the MSE and other statistics here:

```
> cvmodel@model$cross_validation_metrics
H2ORegressionMetrics: deeplearning
** Reported on cross-validation data. **
Description: 3-fold cross-validation on training data

MSE:  39.47373
R2 :  0.03510394
Mean Residual Deviance :  39.47373
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to programmatically grab just one of those numbers:

```
> cvmodel@model$cross_validation_metrics$MSE
Error in cvmodel@model$cross_validation_metrics$MSE : 
  $ operator not defined for this S4 class
> cvmodel@model$cross_validation_metrics@MS
Error: no slot of name "MS" for this object of class "H2ORegressionMetrics"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I should've checked `str()` of the `cross_validation_metrics`:

```
MSE <- cvmodel@model$cross_validation_metrics@metrics$MSE
```